# percent per value from array, message if greater than 80%

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-array

I am trying to get an error message if one of the disks is filed more than 80%.
So we have two arrays which have the data of disk partitions (they can have 3 partitions like in this example or more, but under 10). they always are in tandem and correspond 1 on 1. first element of the array disk available corresponds to the 1 element of disk used, 2 to the 2 and so on.

array1 as disk_available (not always the same as in this example)

```
array1=($(curl -ks -XGET https://API/cluster1| awk '/disk_space_available/ {print $5}'))
echo "${array1[*]}"
65536 65536 65536
```

and array2 as disk_space_used

```
array2=($(curl -ks -XGET https://API/cluster1| awk '/disk_space_used/ {print $5}'))
echo "${array2[*]}"
34856 11672 34994
```

we want to check if first element from disk_space_used (34856) represents more than 80% of first element (65536) from disk_available. if lower than 80% go to element number two and check it and so on, otherwise popup an error message. 
if more than 1 partition (element of array2) used_disk is greater than 80% of available in available_disk (element of array1) save it in another array/list/whatever so than we can print them all afterwards.

i tried this one but it fails, the percent part is not quite correct (got it from stackexchange somewhere):
this code is just my attempt, not reproducible and probably wrong in more than one way.

```
for index in "${!array1[*]}"
    do 
    percent=$(( 100 * ${array2[$index]} / ${array1[$index]} + (1000 * ${array2[$index]} / ${array1[$index]}  % 10 >= 5 ? 1 : 0) ))
    if [ "$percent" -gt 80 ]; then
    a0+=("FAIL - Storage is $percent% full")
    fi
    done
```

Comment: What is `array`, what is `a0`? What do you expect? For me it seems working fine after replace `array` to `array1` and `a0+=(..)`. with `echo` ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You say that the arrays are called `disk_available` and `disk_space_used`. Your sample code doesn't reference those arrays at all.

Comment: like I said, the array1 stands for full capacity, array2 for used capacity. maybe it is need it a 2 for and not 1!? i don’t have a reproducible code as i don t really know how to solve it. a0 is an array if all 3 elements of used capcity are over 80% so i save them all and print afterwards

Comment: Those disk space numbers should come from somewhere. A file, a command? Please [edit] the question with that information.

Comment: i edited it, it comes from a curl against an API

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You see, it's important to add some context to questions to enable others to give good answers :-) Use `for index in "${!array1[@]}"` instead of `*`, this should make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normaly a percentage op needs total/used not avail/used !

in array or parametrs when we use * insteed of @ we get one string where you can't loop over!

anyhow try this

```
#get data from api save it to variable in order to avoide calling it twice (resources consumption and asyncroned results)!
disk_infos="$(curl -ks -XGET https://API/cluster1)";
# extract disk_space_available frome results 
disk_available=($(awk '/disk_space_available/ {print $5}' <<< "${disk_infos}"));
# extract disk_space_used from same results 
disk_used=($(awk '/disk_space_used/ {print $5}' <<< "${disk_infos}"));
# declare empty array for holding errors
disk_errors=();
# loop over arrays
for i in "${!disk_used[@]}";do 
    used_perc=$((disk_used[i]*100/disk_available[i])); # calculate percentage
    if [[ "${used_perc}" -gt 80 ]]; then # check perc value if greeter than 80
        disk_errors+=("FAIL - Storage is ${used_perc}% full at index ${i}"); # append the error to the holder 
    fi
done
# check if errors were encountred
if ((${#disk_errors[@]}));then # check if disk_errors count is not 0
    echo ${#disk_errors[@]} errors found; # print errors count
    printf '%s\n' "${disk_errors[@]}" ; # print each error msg in a line
else
    echo everything is fine ${#disk_errors[@]} errors found; # print errors count 
fi
```

Comment: i did not understood what for the "<<< disk_infos" and i did not applied it in my end script. my arrays were correctly filled. but the part with the looping i got it with your script, thank you. now it correctly gets the percentage per partition  in my end script and i get all the full disk reports. thank you Jonah!

Comment: `cmd <<< "$variable"` is_like `echo "$variable | cmd"`

Comment: okeeeey, now i got it. no need to query the api more than need it. thanks for the added comments on the script.